# Connecting to Oracle database using Xampp PHP on 64 bit windows server 2008 R2

Tags: php, oracle, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I config the oracle database in local system using xampp .. but the same steps i used on windows server 2008 to connect oracle but  its not working..

These r the steps i used

1) install the Oracle instantClient

2)Uncomment extension=php_oci8_11g.dll

3) Copy the Oracle InstantClient files into php/ext folder and system 32 folder

in php info page oci_8 was not enabled

its worked on my windows 7 system but not working on windows server 2008 
any other steps need to follow plzz.. suggest

Comment: Please edit the question and explain what the error message says (copy and paste, if not too large). Or explain how you detect the `its not working` thing.

Comment: oci8 was not enabled in xampp